# Show that $h:D \to R$ is continuous in $D$.

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove this:

Suppose $f,g : D\to R$ are both continuous on $D$. Define $h: D\to R$ by $h(x)=max \{f(x),g(x)\}$. Show that $h$ is continuous on $D$.

But I do not know how to attack this problem because I think it has an easy answer but I can not see it. Can you help me please. Thank you.

Comment: Using the definition could be of some help, I think.

Comment: But how can I bound h(x) I thought in that but i dont see it :)

Answer (score 3):

It may help to show that $$h(x)=\frac12\bigl(f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|\bigr).$$ If you know (or can show) that (1) addition, subtraction, and multiplication of continuous real-valued functions is continuous, (2) a composition of continuous functions is continuous, and (3) that the absolute value function is continuous on $\Bbb R$, then you're pretty much done.

As a hint for how to prove the last result, you can use the fact below (hover your cursor over the blank space):

> For any $y,z\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\bigl||y|-|z|\bigr|\le|y-z|.$ This follows fairly easily from triangle inequality.

If you've checked the hint and you're still stymied (or simply want to verify that you're on the right track with some portion of your proofs), let me know.

Comment: well we havent seen that the absolute value of functions  is continuous :)

Comment: Then you need only prove it! ^_^ I will add a phantom text hint to my answer (just in case you should decide you need it).

Comment: well I need to deliver my homework in few hours :) can you help me a little more please because I have tried to do this but now my ideas are close :) thank you

Comment: The proof is fairly straightforward. See what you can do (with or without the hint), and let me know if you're still stuck.

Comment: Good and the proof of the equality of h(x) is straightforward too?

Comment: Indeed. There are really only two cases to consider for an arbitrary $x\in D$: (1) $f(x)\ge g(x),$ or (2) $f(x)<g(x).$

Comment: ok I will try to :) I still stress but I will try to go on with the idea :) my Is not working pretty well :( jjajajaj

Comment: I still stuck jajajaj I do not see the equality :(

Comment: Well, if $f(x)\ge g(x),$ then what is $|f(x)-g(x)|$?